# Trying to find title of SF Book I read about 40 years ago - differing realities

Tags: story-identification

The main character found himself transported to an different reality - believe he moved back and forth several times.  Definitely human(oid) in the other place.  One thing I remember about the word choice differences is that the other reality referred to sex as "joking".  Also seem to remember scenes in his den - either before or after travel.  I think the woman from the other reality could come back through with him - and did on occasion.

Not much to go on I know - but I've read so many and this was soooo long ago.

Comment: Sorry but we need way more information. Can you describe the cover of the book? Any significant details about the other world/setting/plot?

Comment: Was this set in the present or future? And were there only humans, or any other type of beings?

Comment: If my memory serves me at all - remember - it's got to be 40 years since I've read this book - can't find it in what's left of my collection - the alternate reality - or universe - or planet - seemed to be behind ours in technology, but did have some supernatural bits. The main guy of course dropped into a conflict between groups. Wasn't Lord Kalvin(sp) of Otherwhen - I remember that one pretty well - and it wasn't the Coramonde books either. I know it's not much - but I'm trying!

Comment: It could be Job: A Comedy of Justice by Robert A. Heinlein - After he firewalked in Polynesia, while on vacation, the world isn't the same for Alexander Hergensheimer.  He now finds himself bouncing randomly from parallel-world to parallel-world. As natural accidents  occurred without cease Alex realizes it must be the devil's fault  because it seems the end of the world is coming... Alex, with his  new heathen companion Margrethe, must explore their faith's because this is something only religion can make sense of.

Comment: Was there a unicorn involved?

Comment: The *Harold Shea* stories are about travel to various fictional and mythical worlds, and they bring back a couple of women from the world of Spenser's *Faerie Queene*, but the part about "joking" doesn't fit.

Comment: I have a vague memory which I can't seem to sharpen. I know I have read a story where people elsewhere use "joking" to refer to sex. I suspect it was by Poul Anderson. I'll keep mulling this over and see if I can remember more.

Answer (score -2):

The Chronicles of Thomas Covenant, Stephen R. Donaldson. It fits most of your description, but is classed more as fantasy.

Comment: :) How does it fit? How doesn't it fit?

Comment: The Thomas Covenant Chronicles really don't fit the description.  Sex is very uncommonly referred to, and never as 'joking' (in fact, there is a rape scene in the first few chapters; anything but a joke.)  Moving back and forth between worlds is also absent; he enters the world near the beginning of the book, then only leaves at the end (a pattern followed by the rest of the initial trilogy.)  The second trilogy includes a woman from his world who also travels to the land with him, but unless the OP is mis-remembering reading several distinct trilogies, it seems likely he's referring to her.

Comment: Might this be [The Warlock In Spite of Himself](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Warlock_in_Spite_of_Himself) by Christopher Stasheff?